# Counting number of neighbors Conway's Game of Life

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I have an error somewhere in this code.
The number of neighbors is not being counted correctly, as per my understanding. The neighbors function is probably where the issue is. My field variable is a 12x12 char array, the '#' is an alive cell and '-' is a dead one.
I am relatively new to programming and would appreciate some help with this.

```
int neighbors(int l, int c)
{
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
    {
      if ((l+i < 0 || l+i > 12) && (c+j < 0 || c+j > 12))
      {
        continue;
      }
      else if ((i != 0 || j != 0) && field[(l + i)][(c + j)] == '#')
      {
        num++;
      }
    }
  }
  return num;
}

//game logic
void logic()
{
  char temp[12][12];
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      temp[i][j] = field[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
      if (field[i][j] == '#')
      {
        if (neighbors(i, j) < 1 || neighbors(i, j) > 3)
        {
          temp[i][j] = '-';
        }
        else
        {
          temp[i][j] = '#';
        }
      }
      if (field[i][j] = '-')
      {
        if (neighbors(i, j) == 3)
        {
          temp[i][j] = '#';
        }
        else
        {
          temp[i][j] = '-';
        }
      }
      field[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The ```(i != 0 && j != 0)``` is for making sure the function doesnt check if the position itself is alive, only its surroundings.

Comment: Ive added both of your suggestions, i was lacking on both parts as you have made me realize. Thank you! Although it still doesnt work, now it produces a weird output. Before everything was dead after the first iteration, but now 4 cells have appeared, 2 of them are correct and the other two arent. I am missing a whole bunch of other ones that should be alive though

Comment: Isn't what you are describing for the or operator? The and only is true if both i and j arent equal to 0

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. Just double checked

Comment: It still isnt working :/
Gives me a weird output

Comment: i have updated my code in this thread

Comment: Thank you, just fixed both but it still isnt working

Comment: Changed some things and it is finally working, thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array has dimensions 12x12, the maximum index value is 11, hence the test `if ((l+i < 0 || l+i > 12) && (c+j < 0 || c+j > 12))` is incorrect. It should be:

```
if (l+i < 0 || l+i >= 12 || c+j < 0 || c+j >= 12)
    continue;
```

Another major problem is you update `field[i][j] = temp[i][j];` inside the update loop: this corrupts the computation for the neighbors of the adjacent cells. You should first compute the whole `temp` array and update `field` in a subsequent loop, or with a single call to `memcpy()`.

Furthermore, the standard rules for [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) are somewhat different from your implementation: `if (neighbors(i, j) < 1 || neighbors(i, j) > 3)` keeps a cell with a single neighbour alive whereas under the standard rules it should die. Change this test to:

```
if (neighbors(i, j) < 2 || neighbors(i, j) > 3)
    temp[i][j] = '-';
```

Here is a simplified version:

```
int neighbors(int l, int c) {
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
            if (l+i >= 0 && l+i < 12 && c+j >= 0 && c+j < 12
            &&  (i != 0 || j != 0) && field[l+i][c+j] == '#') {
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}

//game logic
void logic() {
    char temp[12][12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = field[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            int nb = neighbors(i, j);
            if (nb < 2 || nb > 3) {
                temp[i][j] = '-';
            } else
            if (nb == 3) {
                temp[i][j] = '#';
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            field[i][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the boolean expressions and created a subsequent loop and updated the field variable there, although i am still running into issues regarding the output. It has stayed the same as before

Comment: @LeonardoSantos: there is at least one more mistake. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have actually implemented all the changes already and got it working as intended, but thank you for your time and patience!